# Where to find NgRx version 7 documentation on how to create reducers

Tags: angular, ngrx

I only started using NgRx at version 8, so have only used the create functions for my actions and reducers.

Unfortunately I am now working in a project still in Angular 7, and I want to add NgRx to this.

I have the following

```
export interface State {
   templates: MyTemplates[];
}
```

The `createAction` seems to exist, so I have the following...

```
export const getTemplatesSuccess = createAction(
        `${actionPrefix} Get templates success`,
        (payload: MyTemplate[]) => ({ payload })
    );
    
    export const actions = union({
        getTemplates,
        getTemplatesSuccess,
        getTemplatesFail,  
    });

    export type ActionsUnion = typeof actions;
```

But now, in my reducer, I do NOT have the createReducer. I have tried to find some of the previous syntax, and so far have the following...

```
import * as myActions from './my.actions';

    const initialState: State = {
        templates: []
    }

    
    export function myReducer(
        state = initialState,
        action: myActions.ActionsUnion)
    {
        switch (action.type) {
            case myActions.getTemplates.type: {
                return state;
            }
            case myActions.getTemplatesSuccess.type: {
                const newState = { ...state };
                newState.templates = action.payload; <------ playoad does not exist
                return newState;
            }
                
        }
    }
```

The problem above is that `.payload` does not exist on the action. I have no idea how I am meant to get to this payload that will come along with the success action.

Comment: Something like this? https://v7.ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for older versions are available at https://v7.ngrx.io/

I also wrote a comparison between the two at [NgRx creator functions 101](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/ngrx-creator-functions-101)